# Display Top 5 Entires from Matching Keys in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is a little more complex than the title makes it out to be and I'm having difficulty figuring out a way to go about it.

I have a set of tables which record the 20 highest values and their corresponding keys from a larger list of keys and values.

Right now my formulas are: For values

`=LARGE(Values!$K$3:Values!$K$999,ROW(J4)-ROW(J$3))` for Values and
`=INDEX(Values!$L$3:Values!$L$999,MATCH(J4,Values!$K$3:Values!$K$5000,0))` to select matching keys

This approach works for selecting all N desired values, but will select whatever the top values are, without regard for keys, allowing a column of entirely A values for example.

What I want is:

1. Display top N (20) values with the caveat that:
2. Only the top M (5) values for each key are displayed.

For example, with N of 5 and M of 2, this is what I would want.

Given data:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 200 |
| C | 300 |
| A | 400 |
| A | 600 |
| B | 140 |
| C | 100 |
| A | 350 |

I would want the resulting table to look like this:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 600 |
| A | 400 |
| C | 300 |
| B | 200 |
| B | 140 |

In this system, keys are unpredictable, and there can be fewer than M entries per key, or many more than M entries per key. Values might not be unique, but I haven't found a good way to address this either, and it happens very infrequently.

Comment: Resolved. I have this in sheets too.

Answer (score 2):

max(B) for each unique A:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A:B, 2, ), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

max(B) for each unique A but only the highest N(2) returned:

```
=SORTN(SORTN(SORT(A:B, 2, ), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), N(2),, 2, )
```

[image]

top N(2) values of B for every A and final output limited to top M(5):

```
=QUERY(FILTER(SORT(A:B, 2, ), 
 COUNTIFS(SORT(A:A, B:B, 0), SORT(A:A, B:B, 0), ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A:A))
 <=N(2)), "limit 5", )
```

[image]

Comment: The last one includs the header [see this](https://i.imgur.com/yMSI4uO.png).

Comment: @Osm of course it does... then change A:B to A2:B lol

Comment: you know what, Im going to take a nap - @Player0 I was searching does "Limit" includs the header or not? Lol.